# Shutdown menu option disappeared

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, button

Using GNOME Classic. Yesterday was normal!!! Have the shutdown button after the Log Out...
Please see the picture.

[image]

I appreciate the help

Comment: I don't know how to solve it, anyway, you can log out and shutdown from the login menu :) No sé resolverlo, pero igualmente, puedes cerrar sesión y apagar desde el menú de inicio de sesión :)

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing and holding Alt key.

Comment: It does not work, I'm not using Unity, I'm using gnome-classic

Comment: It helped me in some version of Gnome, gnome 3 if I remember...
Isn't gnome classic just fallback session of gnome3?

Comment: Yes is the gnome-session-fallback

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a terminal you can always use the code`sudo halt` to shut down or `sudo reboot` to restart. I do not know exactly how to get the menu entry back.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using these commands while I can not fix. ty